# how to read parameters from URL in java servlet

Tags: java, servlets

i try to read the parameters from the url in the following way
http://localhost:8080/nameOfmyProject/nameOfMyServlet?query=bla

the code inside my doGet method is

```
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {

 String query = request.getParameter("query");

 response.setContentType("text/html");
 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

 out.println("<html>");
 out.println("the parameter is " + query);
 out.println("</html>");
 out.close();
```

it builds just fine but i get an status 404. 
Can someone please tell me what im doing wrong?
thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you map this servlet in web.xml? Generally the URL would go like localhost:8080/project/servletName?query=bla

Comment: <servlet>
   <servlet-name>ServletNew</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>ServletNew</servlet-class>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>ServletNew</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/ServletNew</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>     Thats how I did it

Comment: What does `request.getQueryString()` return?

Comment: Yup, so you need localhost:8080/nameOfmyProject/ServletNew?query=bla

Comment: @fpezzini thank you for the correction, if i paste localhost:8080/project/servletName?query=bla it gives me at least a HTTP status 404

Comment: @isnot2bad unfortunately also nothing

Comment: How are you deploying your project?  With a war file? What is the name of the war file?

Comment: yes, with war.xml

Comment: no sorry its yes, with packageName.xml

Comment: Is your Servlet inside of a package? If so, you need to add the package name to the tag <servlet-class>. Something like <servlet-class>com.example.MyServlet</servlet-class>

Answer (score 0):

The `request.getParameter("query")`
 will look for the input field called query in the html form. If you want to get the path variable from the url you get it like this

```
  String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo(); // query=bla
    String[] pathParts = pathInfo.split("=");
    String part1 = pathParts[1]; // query
    String part2 = pathParts[2]; //bla
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i changed it like you suggested but nothing changes, still status 404

Comment: do you mean on the web site? its just : The requested resource is not available.

Comment: The log from tomcat or the application server you are using.

Comment: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [27/Nov/2018:21:05:48 +0100] "GET /newone/ServletNew?query=bla HTTP/1.1" 404 949 http-bio-8080-exec-2 1

Comment: this is the last one

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
it was a problem with starting the tomcat server.
Somehow the catalina.sh had no execute permissions. I changed that in the cmd via:
1. i checked for permissions via **ls -l** 
2. i changed the permissions via **chmod +x catalina.sh**

and now it works perfectly. Thank you all!